# SQL querybuilder parameters with accented characters

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine

I'm using querybuilder in my Symfony project to index all my person entities using several parameters like firstname, lastname, adress...

Each person can have 3 firstnames maximum. I'm using select2 in my form to allow the user to write several firstnames in the same inputfield.

Everything is working except the fact that if I'm typing an accented character in the field (like Rémy for example) I got the following error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 730: Error: Expected end of string, got 'é'
```

I tried everything but I cant find the error, here's the code in my PersonRepository which manages the firstname parameter:

```
    if (!empty($firstNames)) {
        $orConditions = $qb->expr()->orX(); 
    
        foreach ($firstNames as $firstName) {
            $orConditions->add(
                $qb->expr()->like('LOWER(ip.firstName)', ':firstName' . $firstName)
            );
            $qb->setParameter(':firstName' . $firstName, '%' . mb_strtolower($firstName, 'UTF-8') . '%');
        }
    
        $qb->andWhere($orConditions); 
    }
```

Can you help me guys?

Comment: Instead of `foreach ($firstNames as $firstName)`, can you use `foreach ($firstNames as $idx => $firstName)`, and then instead of `':firstName' . $firstName` use `':firstName' . $idx`? At least, if I'm reading that correctly.

Comment: Hey Chris,
I did it, but still have the error :(

Comment: For the second part of the change, did you update it in both spots?

Comment: Yeah I did, here's the code :

            if (!empty($prenoms)) {
                $orConditions = $qb->expr()->orX(); 
            
                foreach ($prenoms as $key => $prenom) {
                    $orConditions->add(
                        $qb->expr()->like('LOWER(ip.prenom)', ':prenom_' . $key)
                    );
                    $qb->setParameter(':prenom_' . $key, '%' . mb_strtolower($prenom, 'UTF-8') . '%');
                }
            
                $qb->andWhere($orConditions); 
            }

Comment: Hmm... could you inspect `$key` to see what's in there? I'm assuming it is just integers starting from `0`, but I could be wrong

Comment: The key has the very same value as the $firstName value, thats why I just used foreach ($firstNames as $firstName)

Comment: Oh I just found out! The parameter cant have a accented character
':firstName' . $firstName,
So I just had to remove the accents of the firstname for this case, so the parameter works fine :)

Comment: I posted an answer that does something similar, but offers better control of the user input.

Comment: @AureSanta don't you understand that by adding **values** to placeholder names you are making all **SQL injection protection useless**?

Comment: Hello, yeah I did edit my code to secure it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think this should work. Since your array keys are the same as the values we'll just manually keep track of the index.

The way you are building the parameters you are effectively making `:prenom_Rémy`, and it appears you can't use such characters in the placeholders/parameters.

Your comment mentioned just removing the accents, however I'd instead recommend going with something you can better control such as an incrementing number.

```php
if (!empty($prenoms)) {
    $orConditions = $qb->expr()->orX();
    $idx = 0;
    foreach ($prenoms as $prenom) {
        $orConditions->add($qb->expr()->like('LOWER(ip.prenom)', ':prenom_'.$idx));
        $qb->setParameter(':prenom_'.$idx, '%'.mb_strtolower($prenom, 'UTF-8').'%');
        $idx++;
    }
    $qb->andWhere($orConditions);
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris, your approach is better than mine, thank you so much for the time you took for it, have a nice day! :)